# Change a referenced variable in BASH

Tags: bash, function, pointers, reference, global-variables

I am intending to change a global variable inside a function in BASH, however I don't get a clue about how to do it. This is my code:

```
CANDIDATES[5]="1 2 3 4 5 6"
random_mutate()
{
a=$1 #assign name of input variable to "a"
insides=${!a} #See input variable value
RNDM_PARAM=`echo $[ 1 + $[ RANDOM % 5 ]]` #change random position in input variable
NEW_PAR=99 #value to substitute
ARR=($insides) #Convert string to array
ARR[$RNDM_PARAM]=$NEW_PAR #Change the random position
NEW_GUY=$( IFS=$' '; echo "${ARR[*]}" ) #Convert array once more to string 
echo "$NEW_GUY" 
### NOW, How to assign NEW_GUY TO CANDIDATES[5]?
}

random_mutate CANDIDATES[5]
```

I would like to be able to assign NEW_GUY to the variable referenced by $1 or to another variable that would be pointed by $2 (not incuded in the code). I don't want to do the direct assignation in the code as I intend to use the function for multiple possible inputs (in fact, the assignation NEW_PAR=99 is quite more complicated in my original code as it implies the selection of a number depending the position in a range of random values using an R function, but for the sake of simplicity I included it this way).

Hopefully this is clear enough. Please let me know if you need further information.

Thank you,

Libertad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval "$a=\$NEW_GUY"
```

Be careful and only use it if the value of `$a` is safe (imagine what happens if `$a` is set to `rm -rf / ; a`).